# How do I get multiple elements out of an array that match a specific value

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I get specific elements out of an array that match a numeric value. Here is part of an excercise I'm working through to try to make this happen:

```
function countCoins() {
    var Coins = document.clubForm.coinJar.value;

    if(Coins != '' && isNaN(Coins) != true) {
        var coinType = Coins.split(",");

        for(Compare = 0; Compare < coinType.length; Compare++) {
            if(Compare == '1') {
                var PennyCount = document.getElementById('Penny');
                PennyCount.innerHTML = pennies.length;
            }
        }
```

So as I itterate over the coinType array how do I get multiple values that equal 1 into a new array?

Comment: There will only be one element in the array with Compare == 1

Comment: yeah that is another part of my problem, I only get the array index one, I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple elements that match the value of 1....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var _arrHolder = [];
 function countCoins()
 {
    var Coins = document.clubForm.coinJar.value;

    if(Coins != '' && isNaN(Coins) != true)
    {
        var coinType = Coins.split(",");

    for ( Compare = 0; Compare < coinType.length; Compare++)
    {
    if(Compare == '1')
        {
        var PennyCount = document.getElementById('Penny');
        PennyCount.innerHTML = pennies.length;
        _arrHolder.push(coinType[Compare]); // <-- push what you want into the array here.
        }
   }
```